# Mostrar varios registros con AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Necesito mostrar varios registros que hago a una BD pero hacerlo con ajax. Les explico como funciona el sistema en el que trabajo.

La primera pagina lista una tabla empleados junto con otra llamada nomina para relacionar cada registro con un monto correspondiente a una nomina de un mes, coloco lo mas esencial del codigo:

```html
<tbody>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados INNER JOIN nomina ON nomina.codigoRac=empleados.codigoRac";
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                      ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['mes']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['ano']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
                          <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
```

[image: Pagina principal]

Cada button tiene su data-id con el codigoRac.

Con esta función muestro el formulario:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#example1 tbody').on('click','.view', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#view').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Lista de Asignaciones</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asignación</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asignacion">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="concepto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Monto</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="add"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Los valores que se muestran en el formulario me los traigo con AJAX asi:

```js
function getRow(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'payroll_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#asignacion').val(response.asignacionId);
      $('#monto').val(response.monto);
    }
  });
}
```

Mediante esta consulta:

```
<?php 
include 'includes/session.php';

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM asigna_empleado WHERE codigoRac = '$id'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

        echo json_encode($row);
}?>
```

Aclaro:

Tengo una tabla empleados con datos básicos; codigoRac(llave primaria)nombre, apellido, etc...
Otra tabla con asignaciones, que tiene asignacionId, concepto, valor
Otra tabla que seria una relacion entre ambas, que posee codigoRac, asignacionId, mes, ano y monto.

En esta ultima tabla habrán varios registros del mismo empleado pero con diferente asignacionId y monto, con el codigo que uso ajax funciona para un solo registro, donde muestro cada parte del arreglo en un input, pero necesito que haga lo mismo para varios registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer que payroll_row.php devuelva un JSON con los resultados de tu tabla, y en la funcion getRow() de tu javascript la recorras con un bucle FOR para ir mostrando los resultados (en el formato que quieras, yo te recomiendo una tabla) en el body del modal.

En resumen, tu archivo payroll_row.php deberia quedar asi:

```
<?php 
include 'includes/session.php';
//variable que contendra el JSON a devolver
$array=array();

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM asigna_empleado WHERE codigoRac = '$id'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    //agregar una fila mas al array
    array_push($array,array(
    "asignacionId"=>$fila["asignacionId"],
    "mes"=>$fila["mes"],
    "ano"=>$fila["ano"],
    "monto"=>$fila["monto"]));
}
//devolver el array como un JSON
echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

Luego, en la funcion getRow() deberías recorrer el JSON, y mostrar cada "item" en el body del modal. En este caso, se crearán 2 input con sus respectivos label para cada registro de tu BD, pero bien podrías modificar esto para mostrar una tabla o cualquier otro formato.

```
function getRow(id){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'payroll_row.php',
data: {id:id},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){
  var contenido="";
  //vaciamos el body del modal
  $(".modal-body").empty();
  var obj=JSON.parse(response);
  //aqui recorremos el JSON con un bucle simple
  for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
  {
     //armamos el html que se agregara al modal
     contenido =  '<div class="form-group">';
     contenido += '<label for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asignación</label>';
     contenido += '<div class="col-sm-9">';
     contenido += '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+obj[i].asignacionId+'">';
     contenido += '</div></div>';
     contenido +=  '<div class="form-group">';
     contenido += '<label for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Monto</label>';
     contenido += '<div class="col-sm-9">';
     contenido += '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+obj[i].monto+'">';
     contenido += '</div></div>';
     //agregamos el html creado al body del modal
     $(".modal-body").append(contenido);
  }
}
});
}
```

Comment: Agradecido por la respuesta, pero una duda, en el archivo modal donde esta el modal-body tengo que dejar los inputs y los label que anteriormente estaban? o dejo ese div totalmente vacio?

Comment: Trato de hacerlo funcionar pero en el ajax solo llega hasta el punto donde limpia el modal-body, no muestra inputs

Comment: Lo correcto sería que dejes el div totalmente vacío. Respecto a tu nuevo problema, te está dando algún error en la consola? El archivo php devuelve correctamente el JSON?

Comment: Correcto, me sale esto: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (payroll.php:696)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Quizás haya un error en el JSON que es generado en el php, lo puedes revisar y ver si php devuelve algún error también?

Comment: Para lograr quitar el error quite el include 'includes/session.php'; del payroll_row.php, pero sigue sin mostrar nada